# get value of a variable if the string name is the exact same

Tags: python, function, variables

consider we have a set of variables A,B,C, .. X,Y,Z all already defined, with each variable representing an integer 0,1,2, ... 23,24,25 respectively.

e.g. A = 0, B = 1

Now I would like to write code which takes the name of the variable as an input and returns their values after processing them.

Here is some example code to perform this.

```
inp1 = input("Enter letter 1->")
inp2 = input("Enter letter 2->")

def connect(inp1,inp2):
    print(str(inp1) + " = " + str(inp2) + "\n")
```

which I would like to return

```
0 = 1
```

if the inputs were A, B.

Currently the code would produce this result instead, as the data inputted is in string format:

```
A = B
```

To get around this I have made a small function to get the value from the string input:

```
def get_value(x):
    if x == "A":
        return A
    elif x == "B":
        return B
```

As you can see, this is infeasible for a large number of variables as I would have to write these rules for every variable. I would like to know if there is a way to get the value without using this function (Which simply returns the value if the string name is the same) e.g. by using a built-in function.

Apologies for my english,
Forp

For reference, here is my example code completed:

```
A = 0
B = 1
inp1 = "A"
inp2 = "B"

def get_value(char):
    if char == "A":
        return A
    elif char == "B":
        return B

def connect(inp1,inp2):
    part1 = get_value(inp1)
    part2 = get_value(inp2)
    print(str(part1) + " = " + str(part2) + "\n")

connect(inp1,inp2)
```

Comment: You might want to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `eval(inp1)` to get value by variable name, but this is not very secure. Go ahead if it's a pet project, though.
You can also get variable's value from `locals()` or `globals()` which are both dicts.

Comment: This should work fine, but can I ask why using eval is not secure ?

Comment: Well, the function itself is totally fine. It's the way you use it. If it is used at production and evals user's input, then you might be up to some penetration attacks.

Answer (score 0):

The ord() function returns the number representing the unicode code of a specified character in base 10.

```
def connect(inp1,inp2):
part1 = ord(inp1) - 65
part2 = ord(inp2) - 65
print(str(part1) + " = " + str(part2) + "\n")

def main():
    inp1 = input("Enter letter 1->")
    inp2 = input("Enter letter 2->")
    connect(inp1, inp2)

main()
```

The reason of deducting 65 is because you have defined your capital letter A as 0, B as 1 and so on as the ASCII value of 'A' is 65

EDIT:

If you want to also ensure small letters are converted to capital letters, you can use the .upper() function

```
inp1 = input("Enter letter 1->").upper()
inp2 = input("Enter letter 2->").upper()
```

Comment: sorry, the variables I used were placeholders for a large dataset, not the actual ones I was using.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary. I don't know if you are allowed for this specific exercise, but I think that would be the easiest way. It would be something like this:

```
variables = {'A':0, 'B':1, 'C':2}
inp1 = input('Enter letter: ')
inp2 = input('Enter letter: ')

def connect(inp1,inp2):
    print(str(variables[inp1]) + " = " + str(variables[inp2]) + "\n")
    
connect(inp1, inp2)
```

Comment: Using a dictionary certainly would be better, but the variables are already set and I am not the one in power to change them, so the question needed a different approach.If you see the post I marked as the answer you can see exactly what I was going for as it completely removes the need for the "get_value" function, which would be inconvenient for many more variables - I cannot hard code them all haha